# How can i configure sql server 2008 using powershell?

Tags: sql-server, powershell, installation

How can I configure SQL Server 2008 R2 Express unattended after installation? Can I use powershell for that, or what?

Answer (score 0):

Try this out not sure if it works with express edition 
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc281954(v=SQL.105).aspx

Comment: I already looked over the link you gave me before i asked the question here, but I find it doesn't answer my question.

Comment: what kind of stuff you want to configure, and what you mean by unattended?

Comment: i want to enable remote connections, and unattended means that after installing it, I can run the script automatically and no one needs to press anything for any configurations to be made.

Answer (score 0):

Checkout http://sql-articles.com/blogs/enable-disable-remote-connections-via-dos-or-t-sql/

You can issue the T-SQL via Powershell or SQLCMD.exe or numerous other methods from the command line / script.